# Meaning of a sentence in context

Tags: meaning

> ESN platforms can be developed internally or provided by a software vendor. They can be installed behind a firewall or offered as cloud-based technology. Vendor-supplied platforms can be standalone or integrated to work with other enterprise software applications such as human resources information systems, contact management databases, talent management systems and learning management systems. There are also ESN platforms that come as an out-of-the-box feature set within some learning management systems.

In the last line, does "**within some learning management systems**" mean that that platform has some learning management systems or they can integrate to them?

Answer (score 1):

No, the "within" means that there are some learning management systems which *contain* an ESN platform inside, i.e. the ESN platform is a (standard) part of the system.